# VBA Click second item of img scr button IE

Tags: html, excel, vba, button

I'm trying to click an imagebutton on IE by using getAttribute("src"), but there are to identical buttons with the same src-code, so when I use this code, it clicks the first and I want to click the second. Can somebody help me?

This is the code I use to click the first button:

```
Set allInputs = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("img")
For Each Element In allInputs  
If Element.getAttribute("src") = "/forms/Content/Images/0006.gif" Then
Element.Click
   Exit For
End If 
Next Element
```

The HTML code for the buttons are:

```
<tr class="jqgfirstrow" role="row" 

<tr tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" id="1" role="row"
 < img src="/forms/Content/Images/0006.gif"


<tr tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" id="2" role="row
 < img src="/forms/Content/Images/0006.gif"
```

Comment: All Inputs is it returning an array? why not loop "all Inputs" variable and choose the second one? or get Elment.getAttribute("id") and click when id =2

Comment: have you tried using get element by ID? 
IE.Document.getElementByID("2")

Comment: or `allInputs(allInputs.count)`

Comment: Thanks for the usefull comments! 
I have tried getting it by elementbyID and that did not work. 
Miguel, do you have any sugestions for coding? I havent tried to make a loop before. 
Nathan, would you elaborate? I dont think I understand.

Comment: Clyde, when I use id, I just get an error saying that "object dosnt support this property og method"

 `Set allInputs = IE.Document.getElementsByID("2")
For Each Element In allInput
If Element.getAttribute("src") = "/forms/Content/Images/0006.gif"
Element.Click
Exit For
End If
Next Element`

Comment: When I use this I get the error permission denied. So I think my only luck is find a way through what I wrote above
 `Set allInputs = IE.Document.getElementById("2")
element.Click`